# phpMyAdmin - config.inc.php configuration?

Tags: phpmyadmin

With this configuration i found the error

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some
>        extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

When click then the following error is found:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not ok    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... not OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] ...    not OK


<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';


/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem for days until I noticed (how could I look at it and not read the code :-(..) that `config.inc.php` is calling `config-db.php`

** MySql Server version: 5.7.5-m15
** Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
** phpMyAdmin 4.2.9.1deb0.1

/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php:

```
$dbuser='yourDBUserName';
$dbpass='';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpMyAdminDBName';
$dbserver='';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

Here you need to define your username, password, dbname and others that are showing empty' use default unless you changed their configuration.
That solved the issue for me.
U hope it helps you.
[latest.phpmyadmin.docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Your answer has been copied my friend : https://technoteshelp.com/phpmyadmin-config-inc-php-configuration/

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at config.sample.inc.php: you will find examples of the configuration directives that you should copy to your config.inc.php (copy the missing ones). Then, have a look at examples/create_tables.sql which will help you create the missing tables.

The complete documentation for this is available at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.

Comment: I have the seam problem. I seem to have the needed directives in `config.inc.php`, and I *did* create the needed tables using `create_tables.sql`, create the pma control user, and give that user the privileges specified in the docs. Still same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the new version of PhpMyAdmin put the 'config.inc.php' files in 
/var/lib/phpmyadmin/

I spend much time in the wrong dir (/usr/share) as this is where all the files also is located, but changes are not reflected.

After putting my settings in

```
/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

They worked

Answer (score 3):

for phpMyAdmin-4.8.5-all-languages
copy content from config.sample.inc.php into new file config.inc.php
and  instead of

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

put the folowing content:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost}';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '{your root mysql username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '{your pasword for root user to login into mysql}';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

the rest remain commented an un-changed...

Answer (score 1):

**Run This Query:**

---

```
*> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> -- SQL Commands to set up the pmadb as described in the documentation.
> --
> -- This file is meant for use with MySQL 5 and above!
> --
> -- This script expects the user pma to already be existing. If we would put a
> -- line here to create him too many users might just use this script and end
> -- up with having the same password for the controluser.
> --
> -- This user "pma" must be defined in config.inc.php (controluser/controlpass)
> --
> -- Please don't forget to set up the tablenames in config.inc.php
> --
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Database : `phpmyadmin`
> -- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phpmyadmin`   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin; USE phpmyadmin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Privileges
> --
> -- (activate this statement if necessary)
> -- GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO
> --    'pma'@localhost;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__bookmark`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__bookmark` (   `id` int(10) unsigned
> NOT NULL auto_increment,   `dbase` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',  
> `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',   `label` varchar(255)
> COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',   `query` text NOT NULL, 
> PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) )   COMMENT='Bookmarks'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
> utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__column_info`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__column_info` (   `id` int(5) unsigned
> NOT NULL auto_increment,   `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '', 
> `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `column_name`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE
> utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',   `mimetype` varchar(255) COLLATE
> utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',   `transformation` varchar(255)
> NOT NULL default '',   `transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL
> default '',   `input_transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
> `input_transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',  
> PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),   UNIQUE KEY `db_name`
> (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`) )   COMMENT='Column information
> for phpMyAdmin'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__history`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__history` (   `id` bigint(20) unsigned
> NOT NULL auto_increment,   `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
> `db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL
> default '',   `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL default
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `sqlquery` text NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`), 
> KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`) )   COMMENT='SQL
> history for phpMyAdmin'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__pdf_pages`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__pdf_pages` (   `db_name` varchar(64)
> NOT NULL default '',   `page_nr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
> auto_increment,   `page_descr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT
> NULL default '',   PRIMARY KEY  (`page_nr`),   KEY `db_name`
> (`db_name`) )   COMMENT='PDF relation pages for phpMyAdmin'   DEFAULT
> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__recent`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__recent` (   `username` varchar(64)
> NOT NULL,   `tables` text NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`username`) )  
> COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
> COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__favorite`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__favorite` (   `username` varchar(64)
> NOT NULL,   `tables` text NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`username`) )  
> COMMENT='Favorite tables'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
> utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__table_uiprefs`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_uiprefs` (   `username`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `table_name`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `prefs` text NOT NULL,   `last_update`
> timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`) )
> COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
> utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__relation`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__relation` (   `master_db` varchar(64)
> NOT NULL default '',   `master_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
> `master_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `foreign_db`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `foreign_table` varchar(64) NOT
> NULL default '',   `foreign_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',  
> PRIMARY KEY  (`master_db`,`master_table`,`master_field`),   KEY
> `foreign_field` (`foreign_db`,`foreign_table`) )   COMMENT='Relation
> table'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__table_coords`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_coords` (   `db_name`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
> default '',   `pdf_page_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',   `x`
> float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',   `y` float unsigned NOT NULL
> default '0',   PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`pdf_page_number`)
> )   COMMENT='Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output'   DEFAULT
> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__table_info`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_info` (   `db_name` varchar(64)
> NOT NULL default '',   `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',  
> `display_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   PRIMARY KEY 
> (`db_name`,`table_name`) )   COMMENT='Table information for
> phpMyAdmin'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__tracking`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__tracking` (   `db_name` varchar(64)
> NOT NULL,   `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `version` int(10)
> unsigned NOT NULL,   `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,  
> `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,   `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,  
> `schema_sql` text,   `data_sql` longtext,   `tracking`
> set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE
> DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER
> TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE
> VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,   `tracking_active`
> int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',   PRIMARY KEY 
> (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`) )   COMMENT='Database changes
> tracking for phpMyAdmin'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
> utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__userconfig`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__userconfig` (   `username`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL default
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   `config_data` text
> NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY  (`username`) )   COMMENT='User preferences
> storage for phpMyAdmin'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__users`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__users` (   `username` varchar(64) NOT
> NULL,   `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
> (`username`,`usergroup`) )   COMMENT='Users and their assignments to
> user groups'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__usergroups`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__usergroups` (   `usergroup`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `allowed`
> enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',   PRIMARY KEY
> (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`) )   COMMENT='User groups with configured
> menu items'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__navigationhiding`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__navigationhiding` (   `username`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
> `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
> `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
> (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`) )  
> COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
> COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__savedsearches`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__savedsearches` (   `id` int(5)
> unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,   `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL
> default '',   `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',  
> `search_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',   `search_data` text
> NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),   UNIQUE KEY
> `u_savedsearches_username_dbname` (`username`,`db_name`,`search_name`)
> )   COMMENT='Saved searches'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
> utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__central_columns`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__central_columns` (   `db_name`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `col_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `col_type`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `col_length` text,   `col_collation`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `col_isNull` boolean NOT NULL,   `col_extra`
> varchar(255) default '',   `col_default` text,   PRIMARY KEY
> (`db_name`,`col_name`) )   COMMENT='Central list of columns'   DEFAULT
> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__designer_settings`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__designer_settings` (   `username`
> varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `settings_data` text NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
> (`username`) )   COMMENT='Settings related to Designer'   DEFAULT
> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
> 
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> --
> -- Table structure for table `pma__export_templates`
> --
> 
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__export_templates` (   `id` int(5)
> unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
> `export_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   `template_name` varchar(64) NOT
> NULL,   `template_data` text NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   UNIQUE
> KEY `u_user_type_template` (`username`,`export_type`,`template_name`)
> )   COMMENT='Saved export templates'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
> COLLATE utf8_bin;*
```

---

Open This File :

C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php

> Clear and Past this Code :

```
> --------------------------------------------------------- <?php /**  * Debian local configuration file  *  * This file overrides the settings
> made by phpMyAdmin interactive setup  * utility.  *  * For example
> configuration see
> /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.default.php.gz  *  * NOTE:
> do not add security sensitive data to this file (like passwords)  *
> unless you really know what you're doing. If you do, any user that can
> * run PHP or CGI on your webserver will be able to read them. If you still  * want to do this, make sure to properly secure the access to
> this file  * (also on the filesystem level).  */ /**  * Server(s)
> configuration  */ $i = 0; // The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with
> $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use $cfg['Servers'][0]. // You can disable
> a server config entry by setting host to ''. $i++; /* Read
> configuration from dbconfig-common */
> require('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php'); /* Configure according to
> dbconfig-common if enabled */ if (!empty($dbname)) {
>     /* Authentication type */
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
>     /* Server parameters */
>     if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;
>     if (!empty($dbport)) {
>         $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
>         $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
>     }
>     //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
>     /* Select mysqli if your server has it */
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
>     /* Optional: User for advanced features */
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
>     /* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
>     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
>     /* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
>      * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
>     // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
>     /* Advance to next server for rest of config */
>     $i++; } /* Authentication type */ //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; /* Server parameters */
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';  
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
> //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false; /* Select mysqli if your
> server has it */ //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'; /*
> Optional: User for advanced features */ //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass'; /* Optional: Advanced
> phpMyAdmin features */ // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
> // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history'; //
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords'; /*
> Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
> * after taking note of the associated security risks. */ // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE; /*  * End of servers
> configuration  */ /*  * Directories for saving/loading files from
> server  */ $cfg['UploadDir'] = ''; $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

------------------------------------------
```

i Solve My Problem Through this Method

Answer (score 1):

Do `Ctrl+alt+t` and then:

1. `sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
2. open ***config.inc.php***
3. test

   1. change config to cookie
      `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`
   2. donot change this
      `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';`
   3. change '' to 'root'
      `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`
4. save ***config.inc.php***
5. `sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
6. restart the ***xampp*** and check ***phpmyadmin***

If it works i think i am glad to help you!!!