# Connect to remote localhost DB

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How can I connect to remote localhost DB from my PC using phpmyadmin?

Description:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client

Comment: this code worked with me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588897/phpmyadmin-config-inc-php-configuration